# How to copy from vim in putty on windows (SSHed into a debian)

Tags: windows, debian, vim, putty

I am using vim on windows and I would like to copy text from a file. Nothing seems to work, not:

1. selecting text
2. ctrl + c
3. ctrl + shift + c
4. right click

Answer (score 2):

Shift + left-mouse-drag

I found this answer as a comment to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46083834/9921564) from [MSalters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15416/msalters)